# How to find a exact string but that is not a sub string in JtextPane

Tags: java, string, swing, awt, jtextpane

I had write a code for find a given string.It is find out the given word,it may be a substring of word or a word.But,I want to find the exact word not substring that word.For example SearchExactword is a one word,I search for string as word.If word is available in text it will highlight but not highlight the substring of word(SearchExactword).Please help me,Thank you.

My code is:

```
public class FindAWord extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
/* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new FindAWord().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
private javax.swing.JTextField searchText;
private javax.swing.JTextPane textPane;
private javax.swing.JButton search;

public FindAWord() {
    initComponents();
}

public void highLight(JTextComponent component, String patteren) {
    try {
        Document doc = component.getDocument();
        String text = component.getText(0, doc.getLength());
        int pos = component.getCaretPosition();
        if (pos == doc.getLength()) {
            pos = 0;
        }
        int index = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(patteren.toUpperCase(), pos);
        int start = Utilities.getWordStart(component, index);
        int end = Utilities.getWordEnd(component, index + patteren.length());

        int patterenLn=patteren.length();
        int diff=end-start;
        if (index >= 0) {
            if((start==index)&&(end==index+patterenLn+1)){
            component.setSelectionStart(index);
            component.setSelectionEnd(index + patteren.length());
            component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

// 
    private void initComponents() {

```
    search = new javax.swing.JButton();
    searchText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textPane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
    searchText.setText("test");
    textPane.setText("test qweqw test asdasdas test");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    search.setText("Search");
    search.setFocusable(false);
    search.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            searchActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(search, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(searchText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(114, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(scrollPane)
            .addContainerGap()));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(search)
            .addComponent(searchText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 235, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    highLight(textPane, searchText.getText());
}
```

}

Comment: You could use a *REGEX* with `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes for this

Comment: First you should probably explain what works and what doesn't work with the code you provide.

Comment: a general advice wich may have nothing to do with your current problem: avoid empty catch clauses at all costs! at least output a sysout or better make a log-entry, otherwise you wouldn't even notice that something goes wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Use `javax.swing.text.Utilities`. It has 2 methods

```
public static final int getWordStart(JTextComponent c, int offs)
public static final int getWordEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs)
```

When a match is found you can check found word start and end. If it's the same as found string start and end offsets then exact match (whole word) is found

Comment: I had modify the code,Please check it once.Thank you.

Comment: I perfectly understand and wrote here how it could be achieved. I don't have time to write exact working code but provide a general idea how it could be implemented.

Comment: I have edit the code with some additional logic.But,it's not working some times.Please check it.Thank you.

Comment: You should compare word start with index and word end with index + length of the search string

Comment: I Have modify the logic,It's not working only the last occurence of a search sting remaining all times working.Please check it once.Thank you:  if (index >= 0) {
                if((start==index)&&(end==index+patterenLn+1)){
                component.setSelectionStart(index);
                component.setSelectionEnd(index + patteren.length());
                component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
                }
            }

Comment: One more drawback is the text start with search word concatenate with some string if search word is available after that string.This time also it will not highlight the search word.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it. Just a simple logic/idea

```
String text="Entire text goes here";
String toFind="text";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
if(toFind.equals(st.nextToken())
 {
   System.out.println("Keyword matched");
      return true;
}

}
    return false;
```